# Retrieving an entry based on the request URI in a plugin controller

Tags: plugin-development, entries, request

I'm working a plugin and part of the task is to grab the entry based on the current URI using `craft()->request->getRequestUri()`.

Is there a way to grab the entry based on the URI from the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the current entry using the `$uri = craft()->request->getRequestUri()` which will return the URI in a format like so:

`/path/to/uri`

To grab the entry, its easiest to grab the element first, based on the URI, using `craft()->elements->getElementByUri($uri)`. However, this will not work because of the beginning slash that is returned by `getRequestUri`. So you must remove the slash using `ltrim` like so:

`$uri = ltrim(craft()->request->getRequestUri(), '/')`

Once you have the URI, minus the beginning slash (`path/to/uri`), you can use `$element = craft()->elements->getElementByUri($uri)` to return the element and then grab the entry using `$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($element->id)`.

If you were going to need this often, you can place it in a helper method on the controller.

```
private function getEntryByRequestUri()
{
    // remove the first trailing slash
    $uri = ltrim(craft()->request->getRequestUri(), '/');
    $element = craft()->elements->getElementByUri($uri);
    $entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($element->id);
    if ($entry == null) {
        // log something and do something
    }
    return $entry;
}
```